# kernel module for netfilter

Tags: kernel-module, netfilter

I have started writing a kernel module for netfilter.

I am able to hook the netfilter and able to access the sk_buff.
Now I am trying to modify the packet(sk_buff) and trying to reinject the packet in tcp stack but it is not working.

My requirement is to drop SYN-ACK packet from a server and sending back a cooked up ack packet back to server without sending the SYN-ACK to client.

I have tried dev_queue_xmit after swapping source/dest IP, source/dest port
and source/dest MAC and recalculating the checksum and then send the packet using dev_queue_xmit. though dev_queue_xmit return success, the packet is not injecting to stack. Any help will be appreciated.

My code:

code is part of NF_INET_POST_ROUTING hook.

```
void do_exp(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Enering do_exp\n");
   struct iphdr *ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);
   struct tcphdr *tcp_header = (struct tcphdr *)skb_transport_header(skb);

   struct sk_buff *newskb;

   struct iphdr *newiph;
   struct tcphdr *newtcph;


   newskb = skb_copy(skb, GFP_ATOMIC);
   //newskb->pkt_type = PACKET_OUTGOING;
//   newskb->pkt_type = PACKET_HOST;

/*changing Mac address */
   unsigned char srcaddr[6];
   struct ethhdr *eth = eth_hdr(skb);
   struct ethhdr *neweth = eth_hdr(newskb);
   memcpy(srcaddr, eth->h_source, ETH_ALEN);
   memcpy(neweth->h_source, eth->h_dest, ETH_ALEN);
   memcpy(neweth->h_dest, srcaddr, ETH_ALEN);

   newiph = (struct iphdr *) skb_network_header(newskb);
   newtcph = (struct tcphdr *) skb_transport_header(newskb);

   newiph->saddr = ip_header->daddr;
   newiph->daddr = ip_header->saddr;

   newtcph->source = tcp_header->dest;
   newtcph->dest = tcp_header->source;
   newtcph->syn = 0;

   newtcph->ack_seq = tcp_header->seq + 1;
   newtcph->seq = tcp_header->ack_seq;
   newiph->check = ip_fast_csum((unsigned char *)newiph, newiph->ihl);
   int ret = dev_queue_xmit(newskb);
}
```

TCP dump is showing correctly.

Comment: Not my forte, but have you confirmed that the packet is going out the correct interface?

Comment: Also it looks like you are not calculating the checksum for the TCP header.

Comment: Hi Joel, there is only one interface in the testing machine. I will try to calculate TCP checksum and try, but I don't think we need to calculate TCP checksum

Comment: Wait, tcpdump only shows packets just as they are entering and just as they are leaving the system. If tcpdump is showing that the ACK is leaving the system, then the only problem I can think of would be on a separate piece of hardware on the machine that the kernel isn't controlling. Have you tried turning off checksum offloading?

Also make sure you calculate TCP checksum using pseudo header.